# Regression with different timeframes for independent variables

Tags: regression, time-series

I have a set of data with different timeframes. For example, the independent variables, one set is for every 4 years, while others are yearly and the dependant variable is yearly. What is the best method for a regression analysis? Do I have to combine the yearly data to have it for every 4 years for all? If so, what would be a good method for combining the data?

Note: Data from Statistics Canada
[image]

Comment: Can you tell us why one set is every four years and one is yearly?  Is this because, perhaps, data was collected, and just missing, or because of some other reason?

Comment: The 4-year data comes from the census that is collected every 4 years. The yearly data for the rest are available.

Comment: Please include such extra information as an edit to the post, not only in comments. Not everybody reads comments!

Comment: Which datasets are you working with from Census?  Usually Census includes documentation on how to handle these gaps -- or you may be duplicating data captured in other years with four year data.  If you can tell us what data source at Census you are using, we can provide better guidance.  Thanks!

Comment: The data is from Statistics Canada (picture added above) and here is the link: https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/dt-td/Rp-eng.cfm?LANG=E&APATH=3&DETAIL=0&DIM=0&FL=A&FREE=0&GC=0&GID=0&GK=0&GRP=1&PID=110525&PRID=10&PTYPE=109445&S=0&SHOWALL=0&SUB=0&Temporal=2017&THEME=120&VID=0&VNAMEE=&VNAMEF=

Comment: Did you take a look at the data footnotes?  I found this which will almost certainly help you:  For more information on immigration variables, including information on their classifications, the questions from which they are derived, data quality and their comparability with other sources of data, please refer to the Place of Birth, Generation Status, Citizenship and Immigration Reference Guide, Census of Population, 2016.

Answer (score 0):

If you review the official documentation from Census they will explain how to combine data across time.  The official documentation on this immigration data is found here:

https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/ref/guides/007/98-500-x2016007-eng.cfm

According to the documentation:

"Comparability
Comparability of concepts over time
The 2016 Census of Population questions on citizenship, immigration and place of birth have undergone little change over time, but factors such as changes in target population, methodology, questionnaire format and applicable legislation should be taken into account when comparing the data.

Citizenship

Citizenship was first asked in the 1901 Census of Population. The data on citizenship reflects changes that have occurred over time in Canada's citizenship laws. A person in Canada may hold dual or multiple citizenships. Changes to citizenship statutes and regulations pertaining to citizenship may affect the tendency of the immigrant population to acquire Canadian citizenship. Historical comparisons must take these legislative changes into account.

In 2014, changes to the residency requirement to become a Canadian citizen by naturalization came into force under Bill C-24. As a result of these changes, the 2016 Census processing of the citizenship variable required that immigrants only be eligible for Canadian citizenship if they had landed in Canada four years prior to the census year (i.e., prior to 2012). For the 2011 National Household Survey (NHS) and the 2006 Census, immigrants were required to have landed at least three years prior to the census year to be eligible for Canadian citizenship by naturalization.

There have been changes to the citizenship question over time. In the 1971 Census, respondents were asked to indicate specific countries of citizenship. For the 1981, 1986 and 1991 censuses, citizenship information for specific countries is available, but only for respondents who indicated the same country for their citizenship and their place of birth. Since 1996, the question on citizenship has remained relatively unchanged, with the exception of 2006, when a note was added to explain the meaning of "naturalization."

Immigrant status and year of immigration

Data on immigrant status and year of immigration have been collected since 1901. The 1971 Census and earlier censuses collected data only on periods of immigration, i.e., ranges of years. Data for individual years of immigration became available with the 1981 Census. Since 1991, a direct question on landed immigrant status has been used to identify the immigrant population. Previously, the immigrant population was defined as all persons who were not Canadian citizens by birth. Data are not available for the non-permanent resident population prior to 1991 because they were not part of the target population.

Comparisons of individual years of immigration and age at immigration over time can be affected by a number of factors, such as emigration and mortality among the immigrant population, survey methodology, and respondent reporting patterns.

Place of birth, place of birth of parents and generation status

Data on the respondent's place of birth have been collected since 1871, and the content of the question has undergone little change. The place of birth of parents was first collected in 1891, but was not collected in every subsequent census. For the 2001 and 2006 censuses, the question on the place of birth of parents was asked only of persons 15 years of age or older. For all other census years, including 2016, and the 2011 NHS, the question was asked of the total target population for each year the question was available. In 1971, information on the detailed places of birth of parents outside Canada was not collected.

Historical comparisons of place of birth and place of birth of parents should take into account the changes in boundaries and country names over time. For additional information on the changes to country names since 1970, please refer to the Current and historical countries and areas of interest.

For more information on census questions and derived variables related to immigration, citizenship, place of birth and generation status since Confederation, please refer to Appendix 2.0 of the Dictionary, Census of Population, 2016, Catalogue no. 98-301-X.

The processing of the immigration, citizenship and place of birth questions has evolved over time to reflect changes in immigration and citizenship policy, as well as increased use of administrative data. These changes have affected the treatment of inconsistencies, omissions and ambiguous responses (e.g., "Ireland").

In addition, the 2016 Census introduced prompts into the electronic questionnaire for the place of birth and citizenship questions. For example, if a respondent provided an ambiguous response "Ireland," the respondent was asked to specify the country according to present boundaries (Republic of Ireland or Northern Ireland). These prompts resulted in an increase in the precision and quality of data related to several places of birth and countries of citizenship.

The 2016 Census long-form questionnaire contained the same questions on citizenship, immigration and place of birth as the 2011 National Household Survey (NHS). However, the 2011 NHS employed a different methodology than was used for the 2016 Census, the 2006 Census or prior censuses. These differences can affect comparability between 2016 Census estimates and 2011 NHS estimates for the citizenship, immigration and place of birth variables. For more information on the comparability between the 2016 Census and the 2011 NHS, please refer to the Guide to the Census of Population, 2016, Catalogue no. 98-304-X. In particular, there is evidence that 2011 NHS estimates for people born in the Philippines were overestimated. For more information, please refer to the Place of Birth, Generation Status, Citizenship and Immigration Reference Guide, National Household Survey, 2011, Catalogue no. 99-010-X2011008.

Comparability with other data sources
Many statistical sources provide information on immigration to Canada, covering different reference periods and different subpopulations, thereby meeting different informational needs. These factors need to be taken into account when comparing the 2016 Census of Population data with other sources, such as the Longitudinal Immigration Database (IMDB) and the administrative data from Immigration, Refugees and Citizenship Canada (IRCC).

The 2016 Census of Population estimates the immigrant population living in private households in Canada on Census Day, May 10, 2016. The information is mainly collected through self-enumeration—that is, respondents are required to complete the questionnaire by themselves.

In comparison, the administrative data from IRCC provides information on the total number of immigrants admitted to Canada each year as permanent residents. The IRCC data cannot be used to estimate the population of immigrants living in Canada as they do not account for any outflows, such as deaths or emigration. Since they provide the total number of all those who have ever been permanent residents in Canada, the IRCC administrative data counts are higher when compared with the census estimates of immigrants living in Canada at a given point in time.

To some extent, the counts from the Longitudinal Immigration Database (IMDB) consider deaths and out-migration. The 2014 IMDB combines linked administrative data from IRCC with tax data files. The counts presented in Chart 1 are for those immigrants who filed tax returns in 2014. Since not all immigrants living in Canada would have filed tax returns, due to age or other factors, counts from the IMDB are expected to be lower than the estimates from the 2016 Census.

The comparison of the number of immigrants by year of immigration between the 2016 Census, the IRCC data and the IMDB data (Chart 1) shows similar trends in all three sources. In the earlier years of immigration, the census estimates are closer to the IMDB counts, as immigrants who landed between 1980 and 2000 would most likely be taxfilers still living in Canada at the time of the census. As the year of immigration moves towards 2016, the census estimates start to move closer to the counts from IRCC, as the number of non-taxfilers, such as children, increases, while the number of deaths and emigrants would be lower.

While the IRCC data (and consequently the IMDB) are based on the administrative year of immigration, data from the 2016 Census are based on the reported year of immigration. This can create some differences between the two sources. For example, some immigrants may have reported their year of arrival, as they may have resided in Canada as non-permanent residents prior to being admitted as permanent residents.

For the year 2016, IRCC data are available for the full calendar year, whereas the census collected data only for immigrants who landed on or prior to May 10, 2016; as a result, in Chart 1, the IRCC counts are significantly higher than the census estimates."